# sklearn Vectorizer (NLP task) : Generating Custom NGrams which are capable of scaling up for n >= 3

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize, text-classification

I would like to build a vectorizer in sklearn which can scale up for higher values of n. Here **n** is the number of different words considered as single vocab element.

---

My idea is that for n = 1 and n = 2, my custom vectorizer remains the same as sklearn vectorizers, but for n>=3, I would like to replace "I am good","Harry will play" with "I x good" and "Harry x play".

Example: Let's consider that I want to build a vectorizer which scales upto n = 4. Now, take an example sentence "Harry will play tommorow".

Then, "Harry will play tommorow" can break as:-

All 1,2 length vocab words, "Harry x play", "will x tommorow" and "Harry x x tommorow".

Since, the order of elements in this vocabulary is same as that for n = 2, and words of form "A x B" will not be any rarer than "A B", I believe that this model may scale better and give performance benefits.

I searched over the net to find a method to do this and while there are many tutorials for building custom vectorizers all of them end up using there pre-implemented n-gram method.